# Examples of books advocating for political/educational reform?

Tags: publishing, non-fiction

I've had an idea in my head for a while to write a book advocating for political and educational reform in Canada, but I'm unsure whether or not it's even worthwhile to proceed because:

1. I don't know of any other books that exist solely to advocate for political reform (other than Mein Kampf)
2. I don't know if publishing companies will consider a manuscript I submit on the topic, given that my credentials for the specific thing I'm advocating for (educational reform) are somewhat (but not completely) lacking

So, I'm wondering if I can get some insight as to:

1. Do other such books exist?
2. If so, are they almost always written by people who are already well-known in their field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers are yes and yes.

1. There are many many books about political and educational reform.  Some are quite well-known.  *[Savage Inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savage_Inequalities)* is one well-known classic (it also inspired a documentary of the same name).  *[Pedagogy of the Oppressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedagogy_of_the_Oppressed)* is another, and *[The Mis-Education of the Negro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mis-Education_of_the_Negro)* is a third.
2. It's very hard to publish any book without qualifications of some sort.  Why would people read it?  They don't necessarily need to be academic qualifications, practical ones can work as well.  But writing with no expertise, credentials or experience generally equates to uniformed opinion-spouting.  You might be able to compensate for this if you are an excellent researcher, and you present your book as a compilation or popularization of primary sources.

One thing to consider is that reform books in general are always swimming against the current, by definition.  The fact that you yourself haven't heard of any of the classics of this genre despite your own interest in it speaks to the challenges your book will face in finding an audience.

Answer (score 4):

A non-fiction book on social reform by a non-expert is pretty much a non-starter. However, fiction has a greater influence on social and political reform than non-fiction. Hollywood is the sharp edge of political and social change. It is rumoured that President David Palmer "24" paved the way for Barack Obama. People saw a black president on screen and it somehow became 'normal'. Almost every popular US TV series included gay characters - and LGBT people became "acceptable".

I have not read "A Handmaid's tale" but the clear message was a future world ruled by Republicans.

Writer's of speculative fiction often create world's based on their own ideals.

Answer (score 0):

There are books on almost every, if not all, type of political reform.

There are books on Men's Rights, MRAs, and the Men's Rights Movement.

There are books on Feminism.

There are books on LGBT.

There are books on family.

There are books on education.

I could go on.